# problem with inserting from textbox to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

here is my code

```
SqlCommand insert_user = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.users (username,password,firstname,lastname,address,country,city,phonenumber,gender,email) VALUES (' bader','123','beno','venp','33','pal','d',''1234','male'," + @TextBox3.Text + ");", badersql);
```

what i am trying is to insert from textbox3.text to my sql email column , the problem is when i try that , this error msg during debuging popups **" Error  9   The name 'TextBox3' does not exist in the current context".**

i tried  '" + TextBox3.text + "' with @ and without , same problem

if it helps , here is all my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

public partial class Default4 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        SqlConnection badersql = new SqlConnection("Data Source=BADER-VAIO\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=webage;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=123");

        badersql.Open();
        SqlCommand insert_user = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.users (username,password,firstname,lastname,address,country,city,phonenumber,gender,email) VALUES (' bader','123','beno','venp','33','pal','d',''1234','male'," + @TextBox3.Text + ");", badersql);

        insert_user.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //insert into webpage.dbo.users (username,password,firstname,lastname,address,country,city,phonenumber,gender,email) VALUES (' bader','123','beno','venp','33','pal','d',''1234','male','pal@pal.com');
        badersql.Close();


    }


    protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

any suggestions ?

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a server side control with the ID `TextBox3` on your .aspx page. Did you rename it or remove it?

As an aside - this is wide open to [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you should be using [parameterized queries](http://www.enterprisedb.com/documentation/dotnet-parameterizedqueries.html) instead of string concatenation.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> i have it

Comment: @Bader - have you rebuilt your solution?

Comment: i am sorry i am not familiar with sql injection attacks or else i am totally noob , if u just help me with the textbox part , that will be appreciated.

Comment: @Bader - I think that explaining _huge_ security holes should be part of explaining things, especially to a noob.

Comment: yea i know , but asp.net in general is not on my interests , i am just trying to build a small local project on computer for education reasons , so if u can help , i will be thankful

Comment: @Bader - so, did you recompile? Does the page directive have an `Inherits` attribute that is the same as the class name in the code behind?

Comment: i think the problem is common on all my textboxes , because when i changed Textbox3 to Texbox5 or 6 , the same problem comes , they are all the same datatype

Comment: @Bader - I can't help if you don't answer my questions.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a typo in your question or in your code? ''1234'   ?

Answer (score 0):

it works , i was trying to debug the .cs page itself , thats why the erorr pop ups , thanks everyone for your help